# Number of Rectangular prisms

Tags: geometry

How many rectangular prisms are possible with a volume of 100 cubic cm and sides of integral dimensions?

Comment: this smells like homework, is this homework? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

(Rectangular Prism is a **cuboid**)

$lbh=100$

How many possible values are there? Prime factorize $100$ and permute them.

For example: $100=5^2 \cdot 2^2$. You can have $5 \times 10 \times 2$, $50 \times 1 \times 2$. You will get more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The answer I have is that there are 10 different prisms, but I can only think of 8.

Comment: These are - 1 x 1 x 100, 1 x 2 x 50, 1 x 4 x 25, 1 x 5 x 20, 1 x 10 x 10, 2 x 2 x 25, 2 x 5 x 10, 4 x 5 x 5.

Comment: Only $8$ are possible if I haven't messed up my counting.

Comment: Thanks for this - good to have my answer confirmed!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty and dumb MATLAB code:

```
for h = 1 : 100,
    for w = 1 : h,
        for l = 1 : w,
            if w*h*l == 100,
                [h,w,l]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Confirms 8 solutions.